# ThreeJS Applying texture on partly side wall of a ExtrudeGeometry without RepeatWrapping

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use a texture on the surface of my extruded geometry. Actually, I would put an image on one surface of the wall side of the extruded geometry.

More precisely, this geometry is 1/8 of a right circular cylinder, the top surface is a circular segment, the side surfaces are composite of two rectangles and 1/8 of circular cylinder curved shape outer surface.

Now, I have encountered two problems:

1) The texture will apply to the all surfaces of the geometry, how to apply the texture only on the curved shape surface.

2) Because I will use the image from canvas draw an image on it, then use it as texture for this mesh, I don't want the image be repeated, maybe just a bit stretching is fine. Of course, I need to make sure the image size is very similar with the size of the curved shape surface.

```
    // geometry
  var settings = {
      amount: 12,
      steps : 1,
      bevelEnabled: false,
      curveSegments: 24
  };

  var shape = new THREE.Shape();
  shape.moveTo( 0, 0 );
  shape.absarc( 0, 0, 5, 0, Math.PI / 4, false );
  shape.moveTo( 0, 0 );

  var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, settings );
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
//texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // CHANGED
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x5588ff,
  map: texture
    });
mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, [material,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x000000,
  wireframe: true,
  transparent: true
    })]);
scene.add( mesh );
```

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ericliu5678/asLq8jfy/6/)

From the demo link, you can see the texture has been applied to the all surfaces, actually I only want that texture be applied on the curved surface of 1/8 of the cylinder.

Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/asLq8jfy/7/ You will have to add a separate extruded triangle to complete the geometry.

Comment: Hi, WestLangley, it is very closed, but still not exactly what I want. I just want to put an image on the front surface of the curve area. Now, I update the code again, instead of using canvas, now I load an image from internet, but I failed to draw this image on the surface. I update the link


http://jsfiddle.net/ericliu5678/asLq8jfy/8/